# Ruby GUI Drawing Packages?

Tags: ruby, user-interface

I am trying to code a plotting graph application, but I need user input (mouse clicks) and a drawing area/canvas. I have found this 2: http://zetcode.com/gui/rubyqt/introduction/ and http://zetcode.com/gui/rubygtk/. I don't care on which platform it can run. The project will be on Ruby. Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try QtRuby - Qt features are the most comprehensive, IMO.

Here is an example of how you track coordinates:

```
require 'Qt4'
class MyWindow < Qt::Widget

    def initialize
        super
        move 300, 300
        setFixedSize(500, 500)
        @label = Qt::Label.new(self)
        @layout = Qt::VBoxLayout.new
        @graphics = Qt::GraphicsScene.new(-100, -100, 400, 200)
        @gv = Qt::GraphicsView.new(@graphics, self)
        @label.show
        @gv.show
        @layout.add_widget(@gv, 0, Qt::AlignCenter)
        @layout.add_widget(@label, 0, Qt::AlignCenter)
        setLayout(@layout)
        show
    end

    def mousePressEvent(e)
        @mousePos = e.pos
        @label.setText("x: #{@mousePos.x}, y: #{@mousePos.y}")
    end

end

Qt::Application.new(ARGV) do
    MyWindow.new
    exec
end
```

Not the best style, but it will do for general understanding.

If you want to draw lines manually, Qt already has such facilities. Also, Qt has a beautiful community and documentation: [example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html)

Answer (score 2):

You could also try Tk, which has bindings for Ruby (in addition to several other languages such as tcl, python, perl). See [tkdocs.com](http://www.tkdocs.com) for an overview and tutorial with examples. For plotting graphs, see the [canvas](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/canvas.html) widget.

Here's an example from that website which shows how to interactively draw a line on a canvas:

```
require 'tk'
root = TkRoot.new()

@canvas = TkCanvas.new(root)
@canvas.grid :sticky => 'nwes', :column => 0, :row => 0
TkGrid.columnconfigure( root, 0, :weight => 1 )
TkGrid.rowconfigure( root, 0, :weight => 1 )

@canvas.bind( "1", proc{|x,y| @lastx = x; @lasty = y}, "%x %y")
@canvas.bind( "B1-Motion", proc{|x, y| addLine(x,y)}, "%x %y")

def addLine (x,y)
  TkcLine.new( @canvas, @lastx, @lasty, x, y )
  @lastx = x; @lasty = y; 
end

Tk.mainloop
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I also want one, with good user support